# Spaces of homogeneous type is seperable

Tags: analysis, lie-groups

Can anyone suggest me some reference for the following proof?
$(X,d,\mu)$ is a space of homogenoeus type. Prove that it is seperable.

Comment: I'd start with the idea that if $X$ is the quotient of a Lie group $G$ by a compact subgroup and if $G$ is separable, then $X$ must be separable.

Comment: It is not homogeneous space but of homogeneous type that is for all $x\in X$ and for all $r>0$.The ball of radius r denoted by $0<\mu {B(x,r)}< + \infinity $ and $\mu B(x,2r)<C\mu (B(x,r)$.